# sharepoint reauthentication for sensitive data

Tags: security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a page that contains sensitive information that I would like to require reauthentication in order to load. I am using Classic authentication mode, not forms.

The first method i looked at was the PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials method, but that would require sending login details in plain text (i think).

I have thought about using javascript to turn off cookies so they would have to log back in, but I haven't thought of a way of doing this well.

Has anyone done this before with SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i ended up with:

a web part on the page with sensitive material which forces an HTTP 401, and then redirects to another page.

this other page has a second web part, which then redirects back to the original page after setting some session variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something along the lines of this if you're using IE6/8 but other browser may have issues with it (look into http-keep-alives).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
    document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");  
</script>
```

That said, it doesn't seem like friendliest UI option to forcibly clear someones authentication. I suspect a better option would depend on the audience and if they are on a trusted domain or coming from an external source. If they are on the trusted domain and don't normally login anyway, this approach likely wont please them much.

Comment: currently im sending a 401, faking the browser into bringing up the authentication dialog, and then with cookies trying to determine if they sent actual login details or not... however sending a 401 seems to break the control flow of my C# somehow

Comment: How about having the classified info on a seperate web app and then iframing the content into your current web app?

Comment: ooooh i like that... though it seems like a ton of overhead for just one page of secure content. i would implement that though if we did not already almost have it the way ive described